# Apache Ignite: Control data

Tags: ignite

I want to ask a question: 
How does Apache Ignite distribute data? 
How can I control the distribution in Apache Ignite? 
For example, I want to distribute more data to some nodes (because they have more memory, and able to save more data), and less data to others nodes 
Thank you!!

Comment: Your question is very broad, could you please narrow it down giving some example.

Comment: I edited my question, can you help me? Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this for one cache you can implement your version of affinity function (https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation#section-affinity-function), but this is not recommended because it will not be scalable. If you just want to specify mapping of node to the new cache you can try nodeFilter in CacheConfiguration.

Comment: I don't understand it, can you explain for me? Thank you!!

Comment: What do you need to be explained exactly? If you have one cache and you want to have full control over distribution you have to define your own affinity function, but this is not recommended. If you have several caches you can choose nodes to store for each cache.

Comment: Thank you!. How to define my own affinity function? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Example of affinity function can be found at the link from the first answer.

Comment: I saw, but i don't understand it Can you explain for me? Thank you!!

Comment: How to choose nodes to store for each cache??

Comment: What exactly should be explained? If you want to choose exact node for the cache you can use CacheConfiguration.setNodeFilter().

Comment: I don't know how to code it. Can you give me some sample code if I want to choose exact node? Thank you!!

Comment: class DataNodeFilter implements IgnitePredicate<ClusterNode> {
            @Override public boolean apply(ClusterNode node) {
                return !node.isClient() ||
                    node.attributes().containsValue("someValue");
            }
        }

        CacheConfiguration configuration2 = new CacheConfiguration();
        configuration2.setNodeFilter(new DataNodeFilter());

Comment: class NodeFilter implements IgnitePredicate<ClusterNode> {
            public Object consistentId;
            
            public NodeFilter(Object consistentId) {
                this.consistentId = consistentId;
            }
            
            @Override public boolean apply(ClusterNode clusterNode) {
                return clusterNode.consistentId().equals(consistentId);
            }
        }
        
        CacheConfiguration configuration2 = new CacheConfiguration();
        configuration2.setNodeFilter(new NodeFilter(ig.cluster().node().consistentId()));

Comment: CacheConfiguration configuration1 = new CacheConfiguration(); configuration1.setNodeFilter( (IgnitePredicate<ClusterNode>)node -> node.attribute("some-attr") != null);